# What is the bare minimum installation suite for unit testing in AngularJS?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I'm attempting to learn AngularJS. One of the things that attracts me is its claim of separation of concerns and unit testability. So it defeats me completely to understand why I should need to install Node.js, or any web server, to test (say) an AngularJS controller which does no DOM manipulation or call out to any web services.

Can anyone give me a definitive bare-minimum list of what is required to unit test AngularJS code?

Comment: Node.js isn't being used as a "web server" here, it's being used to run JavaScript code (in this case the unit test framework and the unit tests) standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going assume that you understand the difference between end-to-end testing and unit testing in Angular, so you're only asking about what it takes to do unit testing, right?

Basically you're going to need pretty much everything that comes with the seed project.  The seed project uses [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) as the test runner to execute the javascript that you've written.  Step 02 of the AngularJS Tutorial (found [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/tutorial/step_02)) walks through writing some simple tests and executing them using Karma.  Everything required to do that comes with the [seed-project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

Those required things are:

1. An angularjs app
2. Node.js (installed)
3. [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html)
4. Some `jasmine`-style unit tests

If you don't want to use the seed project, you can use Step 02 of the tutorial as a spring board and just follow the [Karma docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/intro/installation.html) to download and install Karma and get it running.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You have answered my question (although it's not the answer I was hoping for!). I'm looking at unit testing specifically. This is what confused me - I don't really get why I need Karma (which appears to invoke the tests against a browser) for unit tests. But seemingly I do, so I'll go ahead and install the whole stack. Thanks.

Comment: Karma is nice because it can (and will) run your code against multiple different browsers (or it can do headless execution, such as using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)), which will test your code against the different javascript engines that those browsers use, so you can be sure that your code doesn't break in any of the major browsers.